Using CIKenels for basic computation and processing 32 bit floating points
I would like to pass some information along in the alpha channel of a CIKernel (for example, the pixel index). I built test kernels to test this idea out:
First one that just outputs fixed values:
using namespace metal;

[[stitchable]] float4 TestKernel(coreimage::sampler input,
                                 coreimage::destination dest) {
    
    return float4(0.12345678, 0.12345678, 0.12345678, 1234567.0);
}

And another that is simply a pass through:
using namespace metal;

[[stitchable]] float4 PassThroughKernel(coreimage::sampler input,
                                        coreimage::destination dest) {
    
    float4 outputPixel = input.sample(input.transform(dest.coord()));
    
    return outputPixel;
}

The output of TestKernel is then fed into PassThroughKernel. Then, I converted both of them to array of floats like this:
context.render(testKernelImage,
               toBitmap: &testKernelBitmap,
               rowBytes: 4 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Int(testKernelImage.extent.width),
               bounds: testKernelImage.extent,
               format: .RGBAf,
               colorSpace: nil)

context.render(passThroughKernelImage,
               toBitmap: &passThroughKernelBitmap,
               rowBytes: 4 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Int(passThroughKernelImage.extent.width),
               bounds: passThroughKernelImage.extent,
               format: .RGBAf,
               colorSpace: nil)

When I print the contents of the first four indices of both arrays / bitmaps, I get the following results when tested on a simulator:
testKernelImage:            R: 0.12345678       G: 0.12345678       B: 0.12345678       A: 1234567.0
passThroughKernelImage:     R: 0.123413086      G: 0.123413086      B: 0.123413086      A: 65504.0 

On a device, the results are the same except alpha is now inf.
Why the discrepancy? Somehow, the PassThroughKernel is sampling at half4, which may explain why the RGB values are slightly different, and definitely why the alpha channel is clamped to 65504.0.
How do I get the PassThroughKernel to use the full 32 bits?
Note: I'm using sampler instead of sample, because I intend to eventually sample pixels other than the current one.
This is how context is setup:
var context = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!,
                                     options: [.workingColorSpace: kCFNull])


You should create and upload a minimum reproducible example so we can look at your results. It's really hard to answer "Why does this code behave this way" questions from code snippets.
